# Ruby Error: Undefined Method `name' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have looked at a fair dozen other SO posts and can't seem to find why this error message is popping up.  I have a `_template.html.erb` partial for my `workout` model that then gets rendered for each workout on the `workouts#index`page.

When I try to access the `workouts#index` page I get an error saying `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` highlighting the line with `@workout.name` in my partial.  The full partial is:

```
<div class="container col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="card hoverable">
    <div class="card-image">
      <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight z-depth-1">
          <%#= link_to workout.workout_img class: "img-responsive" alt: "" %>
          <div class="mask waves-effect"></div>
      </div>
      <span class="card-title"><%= @workout.name %></span>
  </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <p><strong>Workout Type: </strong><%= @workout.workout_type %></p>
      <p><strong>Goal: </strong><%= @workout.teaser %></p>
      <p><%= @workout.description %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-action">
      <a class="red-text"><%= @workout.video %></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My `workouts#index` page uses this to render the partial:

```
  <%= @workouts.each do |w| %>
    <%= render "workouts/template" %>
  <% end %>
```

My workout model is (I don't see how this would affect things, but just for completeness' sake):

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :exercises
end
```

My workouts controller is:

```
class WorkoutsController < ApplicationController
def index
  @workouts = Workout.all
end

def show
  @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @workout = Workout.new
end

def create
  @workout = Workout.new
  @workout.name = params[:workout][:name]
  @workout.workout_type = params[:workout][:workout_type]
  @workout.teaser = params[:workout][:teaser]
  @workout.description = params[:workout][:description]
  @workout.video = params[:workout][:video]
  @workout.difficulty = params[:workout][:difficulty]
  @workout.trainer = params[:workout][:trainer]
  @workout.user_id = params[:workout][:user_id]

  if @workout.save
    flash[:notice] = "Workout was saved successfully."
    redirect_to @workout
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Error creating workout. Please try again."
    render :new
  end
end

def edit
  @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

  @workout.name = params[:workout][:name]
  @workout.workout_type = params[:workout][:workout_type]
  @workout.teaser = params[:workout][:teaser]
  @workout.description = params[:workout][:description]
  @workout.video = params[:workout][:video]
  @workout.difficulty = params[:workout][:difficulty]
  @workout.trainer = params[:workout][:trainer]
  @workout.user_id = params[:workout][:user_id]

  if @workout.save
     flash[:notice] = "Workout was updated successfully."
    redirect_to @workout
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Error saving workout. Please try again."
    render :edit
  end
end

def destroy
  @workout = Workout.find(params[:id])

  if @workout.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "\"#{@workout.name}\" was deleted successfully."
    redirect_to action: :index
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "There was an error deleting the workout."
    render :show
  end
end
end
```

Finally, I tried `@workout.name` first but got an `undefined local variable or method 'workout' for #<#<Class:0x007fe1aa3ace68>:0x007fe1b4babdf8>` error, so I don't think this will solve the problem.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `@workout` instance variable in your template, but it's not set. Instead of trying to use an instance variable, set a local variable in the calling template and use that:

In workouts/index, do

```
<%= @workouts.each do |w| %>
  <%= render "workouts/template", workout: w %>
<% end %>
```

and replace all of the `@workout` in the partial with `workout`.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!